# How to select variable for length element while integrating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, integration, mathematics

This might be a really stupid question but I am confused on this thing and I need help. While integrating in physics problem, such as this one

> Charge $Q$ is uniformly distributed around a conducting ring of radius $a$. Find the electric field at a point $P$ on the ring axis at a distance $x$ from its center.

[image: Charged ring with mathematical labels]

In this problem, the textbook has divided the ring into infinitesimal segment $ds$. The ring has the surface charge density $\lambda=Q/2\pi a$ and the small segment $ds$ has charge $dQ=\lambda ds$. After that we simply integrate and find the electric field at point $P$.

So my question is that why do we take the small length element as $ds$ but not $dR$ or $dx$. This has always confused me while integrating in physics problems. I can't figure out with whose variable's respect I have to integrate. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you to watch some videos to understand what these notations mean
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfG8ce4nNh0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are summing over the *source charges* in your problem.  You are basically using the superposition principle, replacing the discrete sum of discrete charges with a continuous sum (*i.e.* and integral) of continuous charges.

Your source charges are located on a ring, and NOT along $\hat x$ or $R$, both of which are constant in your problem.  The arclength $ds$ is thus the size of a small piece of ring, all pieces with constant $R$ and located at the same $x$, and this arclength contains a small portion of the charges creating the field.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply  a question of notation, or in other words, of giving names to things. The differential "$ds $" simply refers to a differential length element of the ring. You could call it "$dl $" or "$dw$" or however you want. As long as you're clear as to what refers to what, the names you give things don't matter.